# Problem with stix fonts in texlive 2018

Tags: fonts, stix

I have been using stix fonts with texlive 2017.  Now I am getting weird error messages.  Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
    \(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1\)
\end{document}
```

I am reproducing an edited version of the log since it is too long.

```
*****************beginning of log******
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.5.7)  9 MAY 2018 10:45
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**stix-problem-mwe.tex
(./stix-problem-mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 4
Babel <3.20> and hyphenation patterns for 27 language(s) loaded.
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo
File: bk10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+stix on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file T1stix.fd. on input line 6.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/stix/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 6.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `LS1/stix/m/n' instead on input line 7.

! Corrupted NFSS tables.
wrong@fontshape ...message {Corrupted NFSS tables}
                                                  error@fontshape else let f...
l.7     \(
       \cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1\)
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 7.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix/m/n' in size <7.5> not available
(Font)              size <7> substituted on input line 7.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `LS1/stix/m/n' instead on input line 7.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix/m/it' in size <7.5> not available
(Font)              size <7> substituted on input line 7.

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for LS1+stixscr on input line 
7.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file LS1stixscr.fd. on input line 7.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stixscr/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `LS1/stix/m/n' instead on input line 7.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stixscr/m/n' in size <7.5> not available
(Font)              size <7> substituted on input line 7.

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for LS2+stixex on input line 7
.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file LS2stixex.fd. on input line 7.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stixex/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `LS2/stix/m/n' instead on input line 7.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `LS2/stix/m/n' instead on input line 7.

! Corrupted NFSS tables.
wrong@fontshape ...message {Corrupted NFSS tables}
                                                  error@fontshape else let f...
l.7     \(
       \cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1\)
(That was another \errmessage.)


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 7.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stixex/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `LS2/stix/m/n' instead on input line 7.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix/m/n' in size <7.5> not available
(Font)              size <7> substituted on input line 7.

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 7.
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 7.

(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `LS1/stix/m/n' instead on input line 7.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix/b/n' in size <7.5> not available
(Font)              size <7> substituted on input line 7.

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for LS1+stixfrak on input line
 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file LS1stixfrak.fd. on input line 7.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stixfrak/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `LS1/stix/m/n' instead on input line 7.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stixfrak/m/n' in size <7.5> not available
(Font)              size <7> substituted on input line 7.

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for LS1+stixbb on input line 7
.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file LS1stixbb.fd. on input line 7.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stixbb/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `LS1/stix/m/n' instead on input line 7.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stixbb/m/n' in size <7.5> not available
(Font)              size <7> substituted on input line 7.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stixbb/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `LS1/stixbb/m/n' instead on input line 7.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stixbb/m/it' in size <7.5> not available
(Font)              size <7> substituted on input line 7.

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for LS2+stixcal on input line 
7.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file LS2stixcal.fd. on input line 7.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stixcal/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `LS2/stix/m/n' instead on input line 7.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stixcal/m/n' in size <7.5> not available
(Font)              size <7> substituted on input line 7.

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for LS1+stixsf on input line 7
.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file LS1stixsf.fd. on input line 7.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stixsf/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `LS1/stix/m/n' instead on input line 7.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stixsf/m/n' in size <7.5> not available
(Font)              size <7> substituted on input line 7.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stixsf/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `LS1/stixsf/m/n' instead on input line 7.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stixsf/m/it' in size <7.5> not available
(Font)              size <7> substituted on input line 7.

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for LS2+stixtt on input line 7
.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file LS2stixtt.fd. on input line 7.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stixtt/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `LS2/stix/m/n' instead on input line 7.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stixtt/m/n' in size <7.5> not available
(Font)              size <7> substituted on input line 7.

! Math formula deleted: Insufficient symbol fonts.
\)  ->\relax \ifmmode \ifinner $
                                \else \@badmath \fi \else \@badmath \fi 
l.7     \(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1\)

Sorry, but I can't typeset math unless \textfont 2
and \scriptfont 2 and \scriptscriptfont 2 have all
the \fontdimen values needed in math symbol fonts.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/stix/m/sl' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/stix/m/n' instead on input line 8.

[1{/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}

]
(./stix-problem-mwe.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 0.5pt have occurred.


LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 3129 strings out of 494041
 36584 string characters out of 6166448
 72611 words of memory out of 5000000
 6928 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 5950 words of font info for 22 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 286 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 27i,4n,27p,232b,144s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}</opt/
texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb>
Output written on stix-problem-mwe.pdf (1 page, 2865 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 13 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 8 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

***********end-of-log*************
```

I get the following error message right at begin document.
! LaTeX Error: This NFSS system isn't set up properly.``
  Can it because the texlive 2018 installation is corrupted?

Comment: Use `stix2` instead of `stix`.  STIX2 is the successor of STIX with more glyphs and better shapes.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks.  I changed \usepackage{stix} to \usepackage{stix2} and my file compiled fine.  However, I am curious as to what could be the problem. I just saw that there is a notice in the documentation that the stix package is obsolete and stix2 is recommended.

Comment: A number of fd-files are missing in texlive 2018. This is a packaging error. I will sent a message to the texlive list.

Answer (score 6):

When the `stix` package was [updated on TeX Live](http://tug.org/svn/texlive?view=revision&sortby=date&revision=47540), the necessary font description `.fd` files were dropped, I assume by mistake as even a new `.fdd` file was added (separate source for the `.fd` files).

Temporary solution until the situation is fixed: copy the `stix.fdd` file in the working directory

```
cp /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/source/fonts/stix/stix.fdd .
```

and run `tex` on it

```
tex stix.fdd
```

This will generate the necessary `.fd` files and LaTeX should be happy to run your old documents.

If you don't have `stix.fdd` on your system, you can directly download it from CTAN: http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/stix/latex/stix.fdd

Use `stix2` for newer ones.

---

### UPDATE

Revision 47652 of the package on TeX Live has fixed the problem

Comment: @jfbu I added the CTAN link

Comment: ah sorry @egreg. The `stix2` support files are found  in `source/latex/stix2` but the `stix` ones are indeed in `source/font/stix` as you stated in your answer (for some reason I read `latex` for `font`) and there is no `source/font/stix2`. Hence my confusion. My comments are ready for deletion.

Comment: The problem I have mentioned has been fixed in an updated version of stix.

Comment: @S.Venkataraman Thanks for reminding, I added an update note.