# Problem with the placement of limits of integration in stix2

Tags: stix, integral

There seems to be a problem in placement of limits in the stix2 package.  The limits are placed too far from the integral sign.
Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix2}
\begin{document}
Consider the integral 
\[
\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx.
\]
\end{document}
```

The output is given below:
[image]

Is there any simple work around for this?
By the way, problems with stix package I had mentioned in 
[Problem with stix fonts in texlive 2018](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430749/problem-with-stix-fonts-in-texlive-2018/430757#430757)
have been fixed in a an
update.  stix doesn't have this problem with placement of limits.
However, since stix2 is newer and likely to maintained, I would like to stick to the newer version. Is there any simple work around for the problem?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a bug in the font metrics, you should report to the font maintainers.

It is hard to make a general workaround as a macro that detects display or inline math, and `\limits` or `\nolimits` cases, and that will not do the wrong thing as soon as the font is fixed.

For a particular case, best I can suggest is adding negative space as in the last example below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix2}
\begin{document}
Consider the integral 

\makeatletter


$
\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx.
\intop_0^1 f(x)\,dx.
\intop\nolimits_0^1 f(x)\,dx.
$

\[
\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx.
\intop_0^1 f(x)\,dx.
\intop\nolimits_0^1 f(x)\,dx.
\]



$
\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx.
\intop_0^1 f(x)\,dx.
\intop\nolimits_0^1 f(x)\,dx.
$


\[
\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx.
\intop_0^1 f(x)\,dx.
\intop\nolimits_0^1 f(x)\,dx.
\]

\bigskip

\[
\int_{\mkern-6mu 0}^{\mkern-6mu 1} f(x)\,dx.
\]



\end{document}
```